# Looking for novel/novella (80s?, 90s?) about history revisionism

Tags: story-identification, history

I recall it as a paperback novel from the late 80s or early to mid 90s. Maybe 200-300 pages (so I don't think it was part of an novella anthology, but perhaps I'm misremembering it).

It involved a plot where the main conflict was preventing others from changing how history was reported in current times.  One memorable example was that George Washington now had a scandal coming to light, but it was a planted story by the antagonists.  The story had a definite sci-fi plot rather than a mere future dystopia (like "1984").

I had thought Orson Scott Card or perhaps William Gibson or Neal Stephenson had wrote it, but haven't found evidence of it by them and cannot find it among my collection.

Sorry I wish I recalled more to go on.

Anyone remember what it might be?  Thx!

Comment: So there were TWO groups of time-travelers / past-alterers at odds with each other? Or was it that there came from different futures - where one wanted/needed GW repute the plummet?

Comment: Sorry, my memory is so very foggy:  I *think* there was two groups of past-alterers that represented different political agendas.  The protagonists had a kind of accuracy curation agenda and seemed to treat the antagonists as a self-serving vandals as I recall.

Comment: Was there time travel involved or aren't you sure on that? The way I read your question I thought it was just agencies rewriting history and inventing stories and events that never happened.

Comment: @Keeleon, I'm not sure.   I was suspecting that _"Pastwatch - Redemption of Christopher Columbus"_ (by O. S. Card) was the story, but I'm not seeing mention of a G. Washington scene though perhaps its in the text...

Answer (score 2):

You might look at ["Dinosaur Beach](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/584217.Dinosaur_Beach)", by Keith Laumer.  I found it in the collection [Odyssey](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-301-odyssey.aspx).

The story is about time travel, where there are several competing time travel agencies (it gets up to six, I believe) running about trying to 'fix' history one way or another.  At least two of the agencies are quite openly opposed to each other.  One of the two is trying to minimize changes to the time stream, without overwriting their own existence, another is trying to make the changes come out well for their preferred future.  There are several time loops as the actions in the past change the future and cause paradoxes.

what doesn't fit is that it doesn't specifically mention George Washington, which is significant, I admit.  However, the premise of dueling time travel agencies was similar enough I thought it might be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks, @Megha.  You're right in that without G. Washington, probably not it, but I know my clues are pretty thin.  The cover doesn't look familiar but it's been a while.  Unless someone else gives me something better before the bounty deadline runs out, I'll probably just award you the bounty just out of appreciation for the effort...

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't get a better match.  I knew mine was a longshot, but I was hoping it might help somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you putting it up there.  Sounds like fun read either way.